# What is the process or steps to integrate Aadhaar/UIDAI with any other application

Tags: salesforce, integration

We are currently developing a project for one of our Indian clients on financial domain(Loan procession, EMIs etc). This project would be built on technology called Salesforce.com. As part of this we need to validate the customer/lead information w.r.t the provided Aadhaar number/Name/DOB. We would be making api callouts from salesforce to aadhaar/UIDAI(Api's) and validate accordingly. So before we get started with the actual implementation we are trying to understand the aadhaar api's and get some hands on experience. Can someone help me with the documentation/detail steps to follow to integrate with Aadhaar.
You quick help is highly appreciated.

We would be making callouts something like below from Salesforce. If we get a successful response in JSON/XML format, we use parsing techniques to parse the response and thus validate the user.

// Code in apex

```
string   body = '{        "aadhaar-id": "999999990019",        "location": {            "type": "pincode",            "pincode": "110002"        },        "modality": "demo",       "certificate-type": "prod",        "demographics": {            "name": {                "matching-strategy": "exact",                "name-value": "Shivshankar Choudhury"            }        }    }' ;

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
string endpoint = 'https://auth.uidai.gov.in';
req.setEndpoint(enenter code heredpoint);      
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setTimeout(120000);
req.setBody(json.serialize(body));
Http http1 = new Http();
HTTPResponse res1 = http1.send(req);
system.debug(' res body -->'+res1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call their web services which required digitally signed request. First of all you should have digital certificate for signing request, there are lot of companies who is providing digital certificate (Class II or Class III type certificates) for signing (For example : E-mudra) and you have to sign an agreement with aadhaar to use their services.

You can check this link as reference for your queries : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/aadhaarauth